# handling multiple clients c#

Tags: c#, wcf, sockets

I am working on a project where i need to connect with multiple clients and every client is streaming live screen capturing to server. Server show that.

What would be the best approach for that.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can use WCF in streaming mode for the video, but I doubt it is a good solution.

I think that going for pure sockets is better, to get the performance required. Showing a live video stream is also not really a limited operation (which is what WCF is built for), but rather something ongoing.

My suggestiion is to:

- Use a pure TCP socket for the video stream for a start.
- If that gives problems, you can switch to UDP. It is better to skip over any lost packages for live video, but with UDP you have to track package ordering etc. yourself.
- If you need control operations, use a separate WCF service for that.

Comment: also, if performance is key and you can still decide on how and what for transmitting screen data, there might still be room for performance improvement there. For example, consider performance differences between PC Anywhere and Remote Desktop.